# Regarding Springboot Security returning login page inside UI

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, spring-security

I am making Rest calls to Springboot controllers and have security configuration which need authorization and roles for accessing certain URL.

```
http.authorizeRequests()        
        .antMatchers("/api/admin/**").access("hasRole('Admin')")    //
        .antMatchers("/api/user/**").hasAnyRole("Admin","User")
        //.antMatchers("/api/user/**").access("hasRole('User')")
        //.and().logout()
        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password")
```

Now the issue is when i gets logout from Spring controller side (like application restarted OR timeout etc), when User gets this call, it returned me whole login page UI. I want Spring to return me some status code and some message saying that session time out OR something which i can get user to call logout.

Comment: well when you try to access something without an active session, you get a 401 unauthorised back from spring security, what your frontend does when it gets a 401 is up to you to code.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the issue is i am still getting 200 Response code with my login page.

so here is what happens in backend, i make a call to unauthorized UI, and due to above security configurations, i can see 2 call being made here, first is status-302 redirect to login and another status-200 with login page data as a response.

So once the response comes back to my AngularJS function, it comes as 200 status and whole login page code as a response.

Comment: thats because you have `.formLogin()` this tells spring to serve you its built in loginform

Comment: Yes ,that is the issue what i need suggestion for. So when a user log in the very first time, above spring configuration works fine as required but how to handle this scenerio when i am already logged in and try to push a button which i have access but in backend session is gone. so i want to tell some notification to user that you are logged out and want him to logout properly.

My issue is that i am not able to identify that because spring is retyrning 200 status and full login form. How do i identify that spring has complained here and asked user to login.

Comment: if you are using the provided form from spring to login, why not just take the html and render it to the client? then so that they can login? you cant trust the client to click logout each time

Comment: Yeah, but that is the catch here, It is AngularJS and using routers so all view loads inside a predefined ui-view only. and hence there will be a view inside a view which will not look good and not a customer experience.

Well. it got the logout called internally by checking the below posted workaround.

Comment: i would suggest that you write your own custom login page and use that, thats what i usually do when i write a react application with a spring security backend, then i just redirect them to my own login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was able to sort the things in traditional way as Spring does not gives me any specific status code but 200 in this case.

I made an instanceof check in my AngularJS controller code like this-

```
if(response.data instanceof Object){
   self.list = response.data;                           
 }
else{
  logout();
 }
```

This solved my case. If there is better way, please comment.